# Trouble with Bayesian Hypothesis Test Equation

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

A passage from Wasserman's *All of Statistics*:

> The Bayesian approach to testing involves putting a prior on $H_0$ and on the paramater $\theta$ and then computing $\mathbb{P}(H_0 \mid X^n)$. Consider the case where $\theta$ is scalar and we are testing
>
> $$
> H_0 : \theta = \theta_0 \text{ versus } H_1 : \theta \ne \theta_0.
> $$
>
> It is usually reasonable to use the prior $\mathbb{P}(H_0) = \mathbb{P}(H_1) = 1/2$ (although this is not essential in what follows). Under $H_1$ we need a prior for $\theta$. Denote this prior density by $f(\theta)$. From Bayes' theorem
>
> \begin{align} \mathbb{P}(H_0 \mid X^n = x^n) 
> &= \frac{f(x^n \mid H_0) \mathbb{P}(H_0)}{f(x^n \mid H_0) \mathbb{P}(H_0) + f(x^n \mid H_1) \mathbb{P}(H_1)} \tag{1} \\
> &= \frac{\frac{1}{2} f(x^n \mid \theta_0)}{\frac{1}{2} f(x^n \mid \theta_0) + \frac{1}{2} f(x^n \mid H_1)} \tag{2} \\
> &= \frac{f(x^n \mid \theta_0)}{f(x^n \mid \theta_0) + \int f(x^n \mid \theta) f(\theta) d\theta} \tag{3} \\
> &= \frac{\mathcal{L(\theta_0)}}{\mathcal{L}(\theta_0) + \int \mathcal{L}(\theta) f(\theta) d \theta} \tag{4}
> \end{align}

**Question:** What justifies the author's step from (2) to (3)? On my own, I can see only that the $\frac{1}{2}$'s can be removed (being a factor on both the numerator and the denominator).

Comment: I'm not sure about *justifying*, but to "translate", they are saying that $f(x^n \mid H_1)$ is the average of $f(x^n \mid \theta)$ where $\theta$ is distributed according to the density specified by $H_1$. I'm not very familiar with Bayesian hypothesis testing but this seems like it is probably just the definition of conditioning on $H_1$.

Comment: AFAIK, the integral in the denominator of (3) seems to include $\theta_0$, which is confusing.

Comment: Since $f$ is a density, what does it matter? There will be no contribution from a single point.

Comment: More generally though, the support of the distribution under $H_1$ should be disjoint from the support under $H_0$, you are right about that much.